# Need help creating an algorithm that'll return array of elements divisible by 5 in sorted order

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

So I need to create an algorithm that'll show array elements divisible by 5 with a range of 0 to 1000.
Here are the instructions:

Let A be an array of n positive integers in the range {0, 1000}. Let m be the integers that are multiples of 5. Write an O(n) algorithm to find and return an array of m elements that are divisible by 5 in sorted order

Here's the code I have so far... So far all I can get in my terminal is 2, 2, 2. I know there's allot more that needs to be done, and I'm stuck. What else do I need???

```
namespace Sort_Assignment
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create array of 0 to 1000 elements
        int[] array = new int[] {0, 1000};


        // Start from 0 and increment parameters by 1 until the end
        for (int i = 0; i <= array.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(array.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 1. _" all I can get in my terminal is 2, 2, 2"_ - you're printing the array LENGTH, not the item. 2. [`%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-) is your friend.

Comment: You have initialised an array with two elements ` int[] array = new int[] {0, 1000};` that'w why you are getting the output of 2,2,2

Comment: You have initialized the array to {0, 1000}. That means the length of your array is 2. now you are running the loop from 0 to 2(2 included). That means the program will print the length of the array 3 times.

Comment: var array=new int[] {0, 250,......,1000}.ToList().Where(x => (x % 5).Equals(0)).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

Comment: You may use counting sort, something like `list[arr[i]/5] += 1`. Sorry, I don't know C#, cannot do more

Comment: @ErangaGamagedara indeed ... `OrderBy` is nowdays O(1) operation as it is single method call :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're not understanding is that this line

```
// Create array of 0 to 1000 elements
int[] array = new int[] {0, 1000};
```

Created an array with two elements

```
array[0] = 0
array[1] = 1000;
```

The other thing you need to understand is that if you want to display the elements that are divisible by 5, you need to use the modulus operator (%).

```
Example: 10 % 5 = 0
```

This divides the number by 5 and the result will be the remainder.

```
Remainder Example: 11 % 5 = 1
```

Instead you can try these two different methods:

1. One way is without using Linq
2. The other way is using Linq and can be done with a single line of code

**CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Initialize array with elements from 0 - 1000
        int[] array = new int[1001];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) 
        {
            array[i] = i;
        }

        // Print the elements that are divisible by 5
        foreach (int a in array)
        {
            if (a % 5 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a);
            }
        }

        // One liner using Linq
        Enumerable.Range(0, 1001).Where(i => i % 5 == 0).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
}
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/365KaU)

Hope this helps!

Comment: It looks good! But is there any particular reason as to why you used 1001 and not 1000? Because 0 - 1000 is the required range.

Comment: I read "Let A be an array of n positive integers in the range {0, 1000}" as an array with the values of 0 - 1000 in it.

Comment: @Preston - could you please edit the question to align with accepted answer? "Let A be an array of n positive integers in the range {0, 1000}." is very different from "Sequential array of integers 0 to 1000" and indeed sequential array does not require any effort for "O(n) …  in sorted order ". The different requirements in the question compared to this answer make all answers invalid - so please be nice to whoever answered and change your question (note that this code will **does not** provide answer to your assignment as it answers very different question)

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the following:

1. Check the syntax to initialize array. In this case since you have to initialize first 1000 elements in an array, it's better to do it in a loop after setting the size of array to 1000. You can also consider using c# collections library.
2. You have to use the modulus operator to check if the number is divisible by 5. when you do a % b, the result is equal to the remainder that you get when you divide a by b.

Refer to the code below for an idea:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }

        int[] arr = new int[1000];
        arr = list.ToArray();

        // Start from 0 and increment parameters by 1 until the end
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] % 5 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Array of N numbers... return M numbers in sorted order... I see nothing that even resembles those requirements...

Answer (score 0):

you can use linq funtions.

```
    int start = 0;
    int end = 1000;
    int divisible = 5;

    var list = System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(start, (end / divisible)+1)
                                     .Select(i => i * divisible);
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (item);
    }
```

Comment: your answer is by far the best, but I guess this will print till 1005, I guess you need  to change `(end / divisible)+1` => `(end / divisible)+1`

Comment: Typo in my comment `(end / divisible)+1` => `(end / divisible)` :) :)

Comment: With using `(end / divisible)` it doesn't print the end even if it is divisible. I tested before post :)

Comment: Array of N numbers... return M numbers in sorted order... I see nothing that even resembles those requirements...

Comment: Question is "an algorithm that'll return array of elements divisible by 5 in sorted order" and I think my answer gives it.

Answer (score 0):

To get an O(n) solution you can use counting sort (since the range is relatively small). Therefore next can be a solution to your problem:

```cs
public List<int> DivisibleBy5Sorted(IEnumerable<int> a)
{
    var count = new int[251]; //count[i] will be the count of 5*i elements in original array
    foreach (var i in a)
    {
        //We are not interested in numbers not divideble by 5
        if (i % 5 != 0)
            continue;
        count[i / 5]++;
    }

    var result = new List<int>();
    //Go through all elements in ascending order
    for (var i = 0; i <= 250; i++)
    {
        //Add 5*i element the number of times it appears in array
        for (var j = 0; j < count[i]; j++)
            result.Add(i * 5);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

List version

```
var l = new List<int>(); // Declare list to load items divisible by 5

for (int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) // Load list with items divisible by 5
{
    if (i % 5 == 0) // add item with no modulus remainder
        l.Add(i);
}

foreach (var i in l) // Print items
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Linq version

```
int[] a = Enumerable.Range(0, 1001).Where(i => i % 5 == 0).ToArray();

foreach (var i in a) // Print items
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```